# Visual studio style error "sa1505"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I keep getting these style "errors" when I compile, and I don't want them. I can't find any reference to stylecop on my hard drive, but everything on the web seems to suggest that these errors result from stylecop. How do I turn them off? They suck.

i.e., "SA1121: Use the buil-in type alias'int' rather than In32 or System.Int32"

Answer (score 0):

Yes those are StyleCop errors.  You might open the project file (.csproj/.vbproj) in a text editor and look for a line similar to this one:

```
<Import Project="$(StyleCopTargets)" />
```

It may have a path instead of the `StyleCopTargets` variable.  You can find the full instructions for integrating StyleCop with your projects [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation).

If you are working on a team I would recommend speaking with other team members before making this change.